# Exception: bus.Bus unavailable - Odoo 10

Tags: nginx, odoo, odoo-10

Currently I have two different databases on different machines that are showing the error below. The first appearence was a couple of months ago, ocasionally showing up in logs, sometimes multiple times in a row and other times only once during a day.

It happens only when running Odoo with proxy_mode = True and/or number of workers > 0. When the proxy is disabled, the error stops.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/bus/controllers/main.py", line 35, in poll
    raise Exception("bus.Bus unavailable")
Exception: bus.Bus unavailable
```

This is my current Nginx configuration:

```
upstream odoo10 {
    server myipaddres:8069 weight=1 fail_timeout=0;
}

upstream odoo10-im {
    server myipaddres:8072 weight=1 fail_timeout=0;
}

## http redirects to https ##
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    # Strict Transport Security
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=2592000;

    rewrite ^/.*$ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    # server port and name
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    # Specifies the maximum accepted body size of a client request,
    # as indicated by the request header Content-Length.
    client_max_body_size 200m;

    # add ssl specific settings
    keepalive_timeout 60;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/nginx/mydomain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx/mydomain.key;

    # limit ciphers
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!ADH:!MD5;
    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # increase proxy buffer to handle some OpenERP web requests 
    proxy_buffers 16 64k;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;

    #general proxy settings
    # force timeouts if the backend dies
    proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
    proxy_send_timeout 600s;
    proxy_read_timeout 600s;

    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503;

    # set headers
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    # Let the OpenERP web service know that we’re using HTTPS, otherwise
    # it will generate URL using http:// and not https://
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    # by default, do not forward anything
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://odoo10;
    }

    location /longpolling {
        proxy_pass http://odoo10-im;
    }

    # cache some static data in memory for 60mins.
    # under heavy load this should relieve stress on the OpenERP web interface a bit.

    location /web/static/ {
        proxy_cache_valid 200 60m;
        proxy_buffering on;
        expires 864000;
        proxy_pass http://odoo10;
    }

}
```

And the relevant part from etc/odoo-conf relating to performance:

```
[options] 
# ...
db_maxconn = 64  
limit_memory_hard = 2684354560 
limit_memory_soft = 2147483648 
limit_request = 8192 
limit_time_cpu = 600 limit_time_real = 1200 limit_time_real_cron = 2400
max_cron_threads = 2 
osv_memory_age_limit = 1.0 
osv_memory_count_limit = False 
proxy_mode = True 
workers = 5 xmlrpc = True 
xmlrpc_interface = myipaddress 
netrpc_interface = myipaddress
# ...
```

This is currently running on Digital Ocean infra-structure, on a machine with 2GB of RAM and 2 CPU Cores.

Answer (score 3):

In your nginx.conf file, add below lines:

```
location /longpolling {
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8072;
}
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8069;
}
```

Comment: I had the exact same error described and this solution helped me ! Thanks ! Upvoted !

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few lines you need

Up to date docs: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/setup/deploy.html#https

Some notable odoo.conf settings, the db maxconn could cause problems with postgres, and there rest assumes at least an 8GB RAM quadcore server, see details here: https://gist.github.com/Guidoom/d5db0a76ce669b139271a528a8a2a27f

```
db_maxconn = 256
proxy_mode = True
limit_memory_hard = 1395864371
limit_memory_soft = 572662306
limit_request = 8192
limit_time_cpu = 1800
limit_time_real = 1800
workers = 9
```

Here's a working nginx config, the proxy timeout & upstream stuff does seem to matter as well.  However, the proxy buffers is debatable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50891625/1689770

**DON'T copy the certbot stuff**, that is auto-generated by certbot, I just left it there for contextual reference

```
upstream odoo {
 server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}
upstream odoochat {
 server 127.0.0.1:8072;
}

server {
    server_name example.com;
    proxy_buffers 16 64k;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;

    proxy_read_timeout 720s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
    proxy_send_timeout 720s;

    # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    keepalive_timeout   600;

    # Redirect longpoll requests to odoo longpolling port
    location /longpolling {
         proxy_pass http://odoochat;
    }
    # Redirect requests to odoo backend server
    location / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://odoo;
    }

    # common gzip
    gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
    gzip on;

    #location ~* /web/static/ {
    #    proxy_cache_valid 200 60m;
    #    proxy_buffering on;
    #    expires 864000;
    #    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/;
    #}

    # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate mypath/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key mypath/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



}
server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```